# Label is not displaying while in delegate action

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

on button click, a scheduler runs that display a form in which `mylab` text is not displaying but when place the same code in the button method `mylab` text is displaying.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        int min = DateTime.Now.Minute;
        int i = 0;
        MyScheduler.IntervalInSeconds(hour, min + 1, 20,
        () =>
        {
            Form form = new Form();
            form.Text = "Modeless Window";
            

            form.TopMost = true;
            form.AutoSize = true;
            form.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;

            Label mylab = new Label();
            mylab.Text = "Pls fill list";
            mylab.Location = new Point(10, 10);
            mylab.AutoSize = true;
            // Set the font of the content present in the Label Control
            mylab.Font = new Font("Calibri", 18);
            // Set the foreground color of the Label control
            mylab.ForeColor = Color.Red;

            form.Controls.Add(mylab);
            form.ControlBox = false;

            form.Show();


        });

    }
```

Comment: Can you collaborate some more information about the `MyScheduler` class? What is the `IntervalInSeconds` method?

Comment: Your question lacks critical details. It requires a [mcve] to know for sure what a good answer would be. That said, your description makes it extremely likely, if not completely sure, that your "scheduler" is executing the delegate in a thread other than the UI thread. Without an message-pumping loop (e.g. call to `Application.Run()`), Winforms objects don't receive the window messages required for them to draw properly. See duplicates. There are a variety of solutions: call `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`, use `Control.Invoke()` to execute code in the correct thread, etc.

Comment: It's not obvious what *MyScheduler* does, but if it's running on another thread, it's no surprise you are getting something that you are not expecting.  Have your scheduler "Invoke" a method on the main form's thread (by calling `mainForm.Invoke`) that does all this work.  That will likely fix your issue